# MySQL Insert no longer works

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working in wordpress and below is my code which has a form tag in a for loop and the submit button. When submit button is clicked an insert operation needs to be performed but the insert function no more works. May be it's not able to pick the id ... help will be much appreciated thanks..

PHP Code

```
$sql = "SELECT 1user.username, 1user.competition, 1user.path, Sum(votes.votes) AS votessum FROM 1user LEFT JOIN votes on 1user.uid=votes.uid GROUP BY 1user.username, 1user.competition";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());

foreach( $results as $result ) {
    echo '<form action="" method="post">';
    echo "<img src='$result->path' width='150' height='150' >" . '<br><br>';
    echo "<input name='id' type='hidden' value='$result->uid'>";
    echo "<input name='comp' type='hidden' value='$result->competition'>";
    echo $result->username.'<br>';

    echo $result->votessum.'<br>';
    echo "<input style='margin-bottom:30px;' value='vote' name='submit' type='submit'/></form>";        
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    global $wpdb;
    $votes = 1;
    $competition = $_POST['comp'];
    $uid = $_POST['id'];
    //$uid = get_current_user_id(); 

    echo 'id of image = '.$_POST['id'];
    echo '<br>'.'competition is'.$_POST['comp'];
    if($wpdb->insert(
            'votes',
            array(
                    'votes' => $votes,
                    'competition' => $competition,
                    'uid' => $uid
                )
            ) == false) 
        wp_die('Database Insertion failed'); 
    else 
        echo 'Database insertion successful<p />';
}
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: when I click on the submit button of the form ... no error comes and nothing is inserted into the database in php myadmin

Comment: The action attribute of form tag is null, so where it will be redirecting. Suggestion: it is not recommended to duplicate the name attribute. You may have to append the dynamic variables to the name.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is solved found the solution 1user.uid field was missing from the select query .. thanks everybody

Correct select query

```
$sql = "SELECT 1user.uid, 1user.username, 1user.competition, 1user.path, Sum(votes.votes) AS votessum FROM 1user LEFT JOIN votes on 1user.uid=votes.uid GROUP BY 1user.username, 1user.competition";
```